# fstab not mounting a disk on boot

Tags: arch-linux, automounting, fstab

I'm running Arch Linux on a Macbook. I want to automatically mount my Macintosh partition when booting Arch, so I added the following to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda2   /media/Machintosh hfsplus defaults 1 2
```

After rebooting, the partition was not mounted, but I could mount it with the following command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2
```

How can I make Arch Linux automatically mount the partition?

Comment: Use `dmesg` to look for warning/error when the system tries to mount your partitions.

Comment: Normally `/media` is used by HAL/udev for automounting dynamic disks like a USB drive.  I recommend putting the directory Macintosh under `/mnt` which has often been used for static mounts from fstab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the mount point fixed the issue:

```
mkdir /mnt/Machintosh
```

Also if you want to avoid warnings, mount the volume as read-only, because write is not supported on HFS+ journaled systems (or you can disable journaling, but it is not advised).

Answer (score 3):

As you said above, creating the directory to attach the mount point to will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If hfsplus was built into the kernel as a module and if the partition containg the modules has not yet been mounted (read: entries in fstab have to be in the right order) the hfs-partition cannot be mounted during boot.

Might also happen if your kernel cannot autoload modules.

Answer (score 0):

Some recommendations ,

It's likely /media will be `cleared` by HAL ,  so during boot , the path doesn't exist , so mount would fail.

You should either change the mount path , e.g to /mnt/Machintosh ,

Or use user-land tools , e.g udisks to mount it automatically (this will ensure the correct path , e.g /media/VOLUME_NAME)

To use udisks , add a mac.desktop in ~/.config/autostart ,

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=Mount Mac Disk
Name=udisks --mount /dev/XXX
Type=Application
```

(Note the second solution work only for graphical users)